# Enqueue object to end Queue and print out its value with python

Tags: python, class, queue

I have a Queue class in my project and i seem to be okay with building the enqueue, dequeue methods except for the print method. My code tries to insert the integer 1 to the Queue and tries to print out its value

```
class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items=[]
    def isempty(self):
        return self.items==[]
    def enqueue(self,item):
        self.items.insert(0,item)
    def dequeue(self, item):
        self.items.pop()
    def print(self,item):
        print(self.items)
queue=Queue()
queue.enqueue(1)
##THIS LINE IS HAS A SYNTAX ERROR THAT print() is missing one positional argument 'self'
queue.print()
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: remove the `item` argument from the `print` method as it looks redundant: `def print(self,item):` (similarly for `dequeue`. also, change the name of the method to something else as `print()` is a built-in method.

Comment: Why didn't i notice that in the first place? Thanks :))

Comment: The code worked, Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey dequeue needs the item parameter for removing the object from the Queue, so dequeue remains the same?

Comment: `dequeue` operation implies removing the front element from the queue so it doesn't need any parameter unless you want to have a different implementation for it. By definition, it is not possible to remove any arbitrary item from the queue; the elements are inserted at the end and removed from the front.

Comment: Just checked the official documentation and it turns out, your right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the parameter `item` from the `print` method in the class `Queue` and it solved the problem.  Also, python has a `queue` module that already supplies this class and some others as well, but I digress.  This is the updated code that no longer causes an error.

```
class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items=[]
    def isempty(self):
        return self.items==[]
    def enqueue(self,item):
        self.items.insert(0,item)
    def dequeue(self, item):
        self.items.pop()
    def print(self):
        print(self.items)
queue=Queue()
queue.enqueue(1)
queue.print()
```

Another idea is instead of making a print method, define the dunder method `__str__`.

```
class Queue:
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.items)
```

Answer (score 0):

You call your **print** method without any parameters. What do you want to print: the whole queue or its head?

Comment: The items i just added

Comment: The items or just single item? If you want to print last n inserted items, just call self.items[:n]

Comment: Looks like a very simple method, Thanks :))

Comment: Btw, your "dequeue" method will throw an exception when the internal list is empty. Reimplement it if it shouldn't or you want to print your own message in this case

Comment: The in that case i figure i should use the `isempty` method to check first?